# How target RETURN for iptables work?

Tags: linux-kernel, iptables

I am new to iptables and seeking your help in understanding.
After going through some online tutorials, I could able to write some rules.

Requirement:
I need to restrict a port, to communicate to few IPs and that too few ports on those IPs. Following are the rules which I have applied

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 207K packets, 32M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 206K packets, 34M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    3   152 IP_SET_CHECK  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:9001
    0     0 PORT_SET_CHECK  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:9001
    0     0 PORT_SET_CHECK  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:9001

Chain IP_SET_CHECK (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.54.59.87         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.54.59.65         
    3   152 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain PORT_SET_CHECK (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 4330,4331,5330,3090
    0     0 RETURN     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:3091
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Even if the request from that port goes to one of the mentioned IPs, RETURN target on the rule is not working as expected. The rule going till the end of the chain and is getting dropped. (Please check chain IP_SET_CHECK for the dropped packets)

I assume that, requests that are destined to reach either 10.54.59.65 / 10.54.59.87 should return to the parent chain after the rule is satisfied. Here though the request is sent to either 10.54.59.65/10.54.59.87 the third rule is getting applied and the packets are getting dropped.

Kindly help me in how to achieve my objective.

Thanks & Regards,
Srikanth C

Comment: So, just to clarify, requests are initiated from your host, they are coming strictly from tcp port 9001 and directed to any port on 10.54.59.65 or 10.54.59.87?